# ACTION_USER_PRESENT not working when app not in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using ACTION_USER_PRESENT Broadcast Receiver in my application, 
My Problem is that : I am getting the BroadCastReceiver only when my application is in Pause state.

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


<receiver
            android:name=".utils.receivers.ReminderBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <receiver android:name=".utils.receivers.UserPresentBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

My Receiver:

```
public class UserPresentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        /*Sent when the user is present after
         * device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone)
         * */

       // MY STUFF - which works when my app is on paused state, but not when it is closed

    }

}
```

am running on Marshmallo 6.0

Any help?

Comment: have you get runtime permision?

Comment: no, i didnt got any permission query.

Comment: I am creating events to calendar, this thing also not asking for permssion, but ended up with exception on PERMISSION DENIAL, if i am giving the permission manually, it works fine... but in this case no such option available!

Answer (score 0):

Getting runtime permision ofr Marshmallo 6.0 or greator.

```
public class RuntimePermission extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (CheckPermission(RuntimePermission.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                // you have permission go ahead

            } else {
                // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                RequestPermission(RuntimePermission.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            switch (permsRequestCode) {

                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // you have permission go ahead

                    } else {
                        // you do not have permission show toast.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                        Permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                            new String[]{Permission},
                            Code);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but ended up with exception on PERMISSION DENIAL` can add here full log?

Comment: its working now, I got a spark from your previous answer's comment : "I am using huawei Phone !!!"

Comment: @bachu thats great if it help consider tick mark and vote up happy coding :)